# Ajax and Mysql Inserting 2 same row for one click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery, pdo

I have a `button` which has attribute `onclick` to start javascipt function and my javascript ajax script has `xmlhttp` object. It is communicating with `dbaction.php`

When I click button everything is okay about script and mysql but the problem is about rows. `It is inserting TWO same row for each click until it rowCount>0` 
and when after first click echo prints `"0"` for `rowCount()`, then if I click again now echo prints `"2"` for `rowCount()`

Where is the problem?

[image]

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadName() {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("sample_div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            $("#my_button").attr("value", "Sent");
            $("#my_button").attr("style", "color:red;");
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "dbaction.php?sender_id=5&receiver_id=6", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
  </script>

<input type="submit" id="buton" onclick="loadName();" value="Submit"/>
 <div id="sample_div" style="background-color: khaki; width:50%; margin: 0 auto;">     
 </div> 
 </body>
```

**dbaction.php**

```
<?php
//Database connection using PHP PDO(php database objects)
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=member;host=localhost", "root", "",    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
 } 
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM friendship WHERE sender_id=".$_GET["sender_id"]." AND    receiver_id=".$_GET["sender_id"]."";
$rs=$db->prepare($sql);
$rs->execute();
$rs->fetch();
$count = $rs->rowCount();

if ($count>0){
 echo "You already sent request...";
 echo $count;
}
else {
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO friendship (sender_id, receiver_id, is_approved) VALUES (".$_GET["sender_id"].",".$_GET["receiver_id"].",0)" );
$query->execute();

echo "Request sent";
echo $count;
}
```

Comment: check your console panel and see if only one request is sent , i think `loadName() ` is calling twice

Comment: what do you mean about console panel? how can i monitorize it?

Comment: browser's console panel in firefox there is a addon firebug install it and check

Comment: if you are using `Google Chrome` then press `f12` (It will open `Developer tools`) before clicking on the `input` and click on `Network` tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the difference :-

```
<?php
//Database connection using PHP PDO(php database objects)
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=member;host=localhost", "root", "",          array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
 } 
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM friendship WHERE sender_id=".$_GET["sender_id"]." AND       receiver_id=".$_GET["sender_id"]."";
$rs=$db->prepare($sql);
$rs->execute();
$rs->fetch();
 $count = $rs->rowCount();

if ($count>0){
 echo "You already sent request...";
 echo $count;
 }
  else {
 $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO friendship (sender_id, receiver_id, is_approved) VALUES (".$_GET["sender_id"].",".$_GET["receiver_id"].",0)" );
 //$query->execute();

   echo "Request sent";
   echo $count;
}
```

in last else block you are using query() and execute() both,used for execute sql queries one  query() directly and execute() for prepared statement

Comment: Ok, this is working properly. But without executing $query, how insert query inserting a row?

Comment: @hakiko see the documentation here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

like @dianuj said in his comment, if you saw two requests at the same time in `console`, then change your js `function` like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var in_request  = false;
  function loadName() {
    if ( in_request ) {
      return false;
    }
    in_request  = true;
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function() {
      if ( xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200 ) {
        in_request  = false;
        document.getElementById( "sample_div" ).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        $("#my_button").attr( "value", "Sent" );
        $("#my_button").attr( "style", "color:red;" );
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open( "GET", "dbaction.php?sender_id=5&receiver_id=6", true );
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```